# Setup AEM Adobe CQ5 6.1 project to build/install offline

Tags: maven, aem

I'm new to CQ5 and looking for steps/settings I may need to do to setup an AEM adobe CQ5 6.1 project to build/install offline (not connected to internet).
I've to use our internal network Nexus (which has lot of general dependencies available except AEM related).
I've to use Maven & Java7.

Looking for possible issues/resolutions, steps & any helpful info.

Comment: I can install the CMS locally & create a shell project without using internet access. When you try to build offline, what problems are you facing? Could you give us some more (technical) detail?

Comment: Our Idea is to make projects build properly on our machine(s) which can not be connected to internet (fetch all dependencies from local nexus).

All i could find is `content-package-maven-plugin` and `content-package-maven-plugin-parent` missing in our local nexus, so i uploaded them. Now, when I run `mvn install`:

    [INFO] --- content-package-maven-plugin:0.0.20:check-signature (default-check-signature) @ MyProject-content ---
    [WARNING] Error injecting: com.day.jcr.vault.maven.pack.CheckSignatureMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/mojo/animal_sniffer/logging/Logger

(1/2)

Comment: I've asked the detailed issue in separate thread, but couldn't get any reply.
Please see: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31597001/aem-cq5-project-giving-noclassdeffounderror-for-org-codehaus-mojo-animal-sniffer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your inputs.
After a detailed investigation, this is now resolved. Just want to share the findings so that it may help others.

1. The `content-package-maven-plugin` which was uploaded to our local nexus got corrupted.
2. Interestingly maven was not throwing any errors when i was trying `mvn install` command on my AEM project. Rather it was giving `NoClassDefFound` error for a further dependency of `content-package-maven-plugin`.
3. From the output of, `mvn dependency:resolve-plugins`, it was confirmed that the dependencies are not fully resolved for particular this plugin JAR, I tried to manually download the artifact from nexus & try to open/unjar it.
4. The artifact pom was corrupted and hence I uploaded the fresh artifact in nexus, and this time all went smooth.

My AEM project is now building fine with local nexus dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

a typical AEM project does have lots of dependencies. There are some dependencies for the AEM platform(including granite, sling, osgi etc). These dependencies are downloaded from the adobe public repositories, unless you have a nexus repository in your company where all these dependencies are available.

Answer (score 0):

If your Organization specific Nexus repository can connect to **internet** and download dependencies (AEM and non AEM related) *atleast for the first time* , then you do not need to connect to internet from your local sand box.

> Theoretically, your organization specific nexus repo also might not be
>   connected to the internet and all the JARs can be uploaded to Nexus
>   manually. But, that would be the last thing I will do in my life !

Your project can download all the dependencies from the Nexus repo(only) in multiple ways.

> Configure the repository configuration in your `pom.xml` file to point
>   to your internal Nexus repo.

```
 <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>internal</id>
                <name>Internal Public Repository</name>
                <url>URL to the public repository of your internal nexus</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
            </repository>
 </repositories>
 <pluginRepositories>
   <pluginRepository>
        <id>internal</id>
        <name>Internal Public Repository</name>
        <url>URL to the public repository of your internal nexus</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

> Change your Maven settings (settings.xml) to use your internal Nexus
>   every time it downloads dependencies (Recommened).

settings.xml can be found in your `<user>/.m2` directory or `<maven-installation>/conf`

```
<mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>public</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>URL to the public repository of your internal nexus</url>
        </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Comment: I've uploaded all the possible dependencies on our internal Nexus.
But while running `mvn install` i get an error

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.logging.Logger`

detailed error in another thread [Error in building AEM project Offline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31597001/aem-cq5-project-giving-noclassdeffounderror-for-org-codehaus-mojo-animal-sniffer)